# Publishing C# MVC project on one environment but affecting another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Ok, this is a very odd thing that is happening right now, so I'm really looking for some advices on what to check.

I have an C# MVC 4 project and 2 Azure environments (production and tests). This is not the first time that we face errors in production environment caused by database structure modifications (that do exists on migrations of the project).

I have 2 publishing profiles, one for production Azure Web App + production SQL Azure, and another for test Azure Web App + test SQL Azure.

I'm pretty sure that there wasn't a mistaken publish to the wrong environment. Even so, the changes from a test migration are present on the production database (causing an error).

Checking on the __MigrationHistory table on the production database, I got the records for my migrations until file 186. The changes that are present on that database are made on migration file 190 (which I ran against test database).
Even though the migration 190 doesn't appear on the migrations table of production database, the changes are present on production database.

Any ideas on what can cause something like that?

I guess the first thing would be to check web.config's connections string right?

Azure's Production WebApp Config (connection strings section):
[image]
(same thing with Test WebApp config page. meaning no database connection strings)

Comment: Yep the two things to check is the web.config file and environment variables on azure. Have you check the latter?

Comment: Ok, my web.config has 3 connection strings: 1st is the local database, 2nd (commented) is test database and 3rd (commented) is production. I hardly ever uncomment one of the latters. The substitution is made by the publishing profile (with the "use this database string..." option).

Comment: As to environment variables on Azure, where can I find them? Are they on the web app control panel?

Comment: The strange thing that is making me uneasy is that there is no migration record on the __MigrationHistory (and ALL the changes are there on the production database as I just checked out)

Comment: You can check the environnement variables by using this url => [my web app name].scm.azurewebsite.net/Env

BTW make sure that no replicat settings exit between the two database.